# Using dative prepositions as separable verb prefixes

Tags: preposition, dative

'Mit' and 'nach' are both prepositions that take dative.

But why does the first sentence use 'mich' (accusative) while the second uses the dative 'mir'?

1. Nimmst du mich bitte mit?
2. Sie macht mir alles nach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are dealing with a separable verb, then it does not matter which case the separable part would take if it was used as a preposition on its own.

The "mit" in the first example is part of the separable word [mitnehmen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mitnehmen), which requires accusative case.

The second example uses the separable verb [nachmachen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nachmachen). It has both a dative object, "mir", and an accusative object, "alles".

Comment: Re the second example: If it read "Sie macht alles nach mir" (=she does everything after me) instead of "Sie macht mir alles nach" (=she copies/copycats everything i do), the it would be an example of preposition "nach + Dativ"